# Anyone know of any other alternatives to Edraw Office Viewer Component or Office Components?

Tags: windows, software-development, microsoft-excel, office

I want the ability to load excel workbook into a windows application form and have all the features excel have if you were to open it by itself. Edraw https://www.edrawsoft.com/officeviewer.php seems to be able to do just what I want. Anyone know of any others alternatives to this since Edraw is fairly expensive once you want the full version ect.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Does it need to support macros?

Comment: What's your problem with Excel itself? is it only price?

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion [Spreadsheet for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/sfspreadsheet) or [Spreadsheet for Windows Forms](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/spreadsheet) support embedding Excel files in windows applications.

[WPF Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Spreadsheet_WPF_CS-1333550082.zip)

[Windows Forms sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Spreadsheet_WF_CS-1980087160.zip)

Note that Essential Studio is required to be installed for the samples to compile.

This control is completely independent from Microsoft Office, so it will have most of the commonly used features of Excel and also provide you with more customization capabilities. Microsoft Office is not required at all.

[image: Spreadsheet]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

## [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) module for Powershell

It sounds like you are looking for a programmatic approach. The ImportExcel module lets you read and generate Excel files.

- Doesn't need Excel to be installed.
- Supports [pivot tables and charts](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/).
- Gratis and open-source (Apache 2.0 license)

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel